# Displaying remote image in home screen app widget's ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-appwidget

I'm learning the ropes with Android development, so forgive me, and I'm struggling to do something pretty fundamental.

I'm trying to fetch an image from a remote URL and put it into an ImageView.  The ImageView itself is within an app widget.

But the image never loads, and a ton of errors are returned.

I created the app widget code using Android Studio's context menu, so the building blocks are, I think, sound.  I created an ImageView in the app widget's layout in place of the TextView that was there by default.

Here is all the relevant code:

layout/new_app_widget.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

relevant bit from NewAppWidget.java:

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

...

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int appWidgetId) {

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    String strURL = "http://example.com/YqLOSfr4.png";
    try{
        URL urlURL = new URL(strURL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)urlURL.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bmp);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mike.widgetapptest" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        android:debuggable="true"
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".NewAppWidget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what are the errors..

Comment: Errors are far too numerous to list in this comment, so I've put them here: http://edge-ip.com/errors.txt

Comment: OK so I'm probably breaking a fundamental rule of Android programming by prompting this "NetworkOnMainThreadException".  Any clues as to how to move the Network off the Main Thread, in the specific context of an ImageView in an app widget?

Comment: Yes, please refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: OK thanks I seem to have solved the original issue.  Now I don't get theNetworkOnMainThreadException error, and the image file seems to be fetched from the remote URL, I just can't get the app widget's imageview to update with the image.  Some further googling required...